# XCODE How to : moving Button to another view

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation

I have a main view that contains 2 buttons (Videos , Songs)

How i can make the Videos Button when clicked move to the Videos View, and same for the Songs Button moving to the Songs view?

Thanks

Comment: you want to go to another view when a button is pressed?

Comment: yes i want to go to another view when a button is pressed but in the same time button moving to another view

Comment: for what are you moving the button to that view again?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[videoBtn removeFromSuperView];` and add a line `[videoView addSubView:videoBtn];`

Here you may need to set the videoBtn frame again to adjust it accordingly.

Comment: I havent tried it.. But I think it will work. let me know the result.

Comment: @BasemShawky I think a better answer would be to ask you WHY? Why do you want to move the button to another view? Just add a different button on the other view.